# How do I sort a JavaScript DataTable using an alternate value?

Tags: javascript, datatables, jinja2

I have a column in my DataTable that has its value (int) changed (str) depending on it's value. It's intial value is 0 - 1, and based on its value it gets changed to either negative, positive or, neutral to give context to the value.

Prior to doing this, my table would look like this

```
Ratio     Item
---------------
0.2       Apple
0.5       Banana
0.8       Pear
0.4       Orange
```

But after doing some HTML side conversion using Jinja/Flask, my table displays like so:

```
Ratio       Item
-----------------
Negative    Apple
Neutral     Banana
Positive    Pear
Negative    Orange
```

But i'd still like to sort on the original float value which is still accessible in the HTML

My HTML code:

```
<td>
  {%if submission['ratio'] >= 0.75 %}
    <span>Positive</span>
  {% elif submission['ratio'] >= 0.5 %}
    <span>Neutral</span>
  {% else %}
    <span>Negative</span>
  {% endif %}
</td>
```

Is there something I can stick in the span like a custom tag to sort on instead, the documentation isn't too clear on this.

ie

```
<span data-sort="{{ submission['ratio'] }}">Positive</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't translate your float values server side, you can make them appear as 'Negative-Neutral-Positive' user-end while keeping initial data available for processing (ordering).

In order to make your floats appear as 'Negative-Neutral-Positive', you might need to employ [`createdCell`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) option. To let that column be still sortable by original float values, you may assign custom data [`type`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) to that, which you will use later:

```
$('table').DataTable({
    ...
    columnDefs: [{
            targets: 0,
            type: 'negneutpos',
            createdCell: (td, data) => td.outerHTML = `<td data-sort="${data}">${data < 0.5 ? 'Negative' : data > 0.75 ? 'Positive' : 'Neutral'}</td>`
        }
    ]
});
```

Then, you may implement custom sorting method for your specific type 'negneutpos':

```
Object.assign($.fn.DataTable.ext.oSort, {
  'negneutpos-desc' : (a, b) => b - a,
  'negneutpos-asc' : (a, b) => a - b,
});
```

The complete demo you might find below:

```js
$('table').DataTable({
  dom: 't',
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: 0, 
    createdCell: (td, data) => td.outerHTML = `<td data-sort="${data}">${data < 0.5 ? 'Negative' : data > 0.75 ? 'Positive' : 'Neutral'}</td>`,
    type: 'negneutpos'  
  }]
});

Object.assign($.fn.DataTable.ext.oSort, {
  'negneutpos-desc' : (a, b) => b - a,
  'negneutpos-asc' : (a, b) => a - b,
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Ratio</th>
   <th>Item</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>0.2</td><td>Apple</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>0.5</td><td>Banana</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>0.8</td><td>Pear</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>0.4</td><td>Orange</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

***p.s.*** note, that you don't even need an extra attribute (`data-sort`) in this case